# Sudden WRONG perception of [name-the-site] about JavaScript being enabled

Tags: support, javascript

I don't know what's going on... I haven't (intentionally) upgraded *anything*, but just now I've been getting this banner over my connections here (Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange - probably more I'd guess) saying, "[whatever platform here] works best with JavaScript enabled" yet I double checked and it has been - and has been for ***years.*** (I'm a few months short of 10 years a user of Stack Overflow.)

Hell, I had no problem *earlier_today!* Yet suddenly it has this error.

I *do* have [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) enabled. But that hasn't been an issue before. Whitelisted are this, and all the pertinent sites, including sstatic.net. The **most strange** is that I was using the site earlier today, and did **zero** updates to anything - I was working on coding a project, could maybe use to look for some help, and *whamo,* problem.

**IMPORTANTLY: NoScript doesn't show *any* sites blocked when I'm on any site here!**

This has be seriously doubting my own eyes!

If, hidden to our vision the site wants to use google or some such, *hell no*, I say, to all the Google-crap, and so many other tracking-crap I don't want. I say, if the Stack Exchange sites want to have extra features, they should develop them themselves and NOT ask the rest of us to turn-on *anything from Google* or any other things we don't want for the rest of our browsing activities. *Why* should we be subject to unknown code "just because?!" ... I would *presume* that the site founders are keen to make this kind of thing optional and not mandatory. This will help kill the site *if* that's what's  going on.

Otherwise, I'm just clueless why this is happening now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does the console in your browser's dev tools say? Any specific js files that failed to load? (As a side note, we *are* using Google's CDN for jQuery, but that has been the case for years at this point. It's not a recent change on our end.)

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)*. It contains input for JavaScript whitelisting, cookies, etc. It includes: "`googleapis.com for jQuery effects`".

Comment: I have a similar setup. I can ***not*** confirm this problem. I tried on Server Fault where I haven't been in a long time - [https://serverfault.com/questions/788063](https://serverfault.com/questions/788063). I am at NoScript 10.1.8.1 (which I think is the latest version - [https://noscript.net/getit](https://noscript.net/getit) - *" latest stable version here, too, using this direct download link for NoScript 10.1.8.1"*).

Comment: Perhaps you have somehow reset your NoScript configuration?

Comment: I got that banner today after restarting the computer (that had the effect of updating Firefox?). I had to add ``ajax.googleapis.com`` to the whitelist. I am at Firefox 59.0.3 now.

Comment: And at Firefox 60.0 after another restart of Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

> IF, hidden to our vision the site wants to use google or some such, HELL NO

Sorry to inform you, but Stack Exchange has been using Google for years, probably from the very beginning, to host its jQuery for it. It's in the source code:

> [image]

So likely your "NoScript" plugin started to do its job and block scripts you don't want.

Since you're so strongly objecting Google, and it's essential part of Stack Exchange client side code repository, all I have to say to you is good luck. (aka if you don't want Google in your life, you won't have most SE features as well.)

Comment: though IIRC there's a few requests to run non google jquery cause of the GFW of china and such. In this case though, ehhhh.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah, "I hate Google" isn't  valid reason for SE to change their code...

Comment: The "hidden from vision" part was apparently overlooked; I'm OK with the JQuery stuff - that's been well vetted. BUT, it was all a bug in the browser or possibly OS as a browser restart cured it.

Answer (score 3):

I restarted my GD browser and this problem went away. -ugh-

...I would leave this up for any who might follow. OR, if yall want, just leave me comments I should close it and I'll delete the question.

Comment: You don’t have to do anything. Meta is a harsh mistress & rep and downvotes here are pretty common and don’t matter as much as on the main site. No need to sweat it.  Thanks for following up.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, Dan.

Comment: I actually think a lot of the bad reaction is to how the question is written - that second last paragraph is kind of confrontational, especially considering that it was a transient issue

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks Journeyman, you're probably right. ... After 41 years in this business (and _still_ coding) I've long learned that my views aren't main-stream. But, while I'm not shy to share my attitude, I also have the thick skin to ignore the slings and arrows of those "snowflakes." At least in my view, a lot of these whipper-snappers would seriously benefit to take my views onboard - or at least think about them seriously. They think they know it all... -sigh- None of us do.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek is correct, without that paragraph I would treat this question in a totally different way. By directly attacking Google you take this out of a professional bug report and make it  a personal attack on something else.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Personal attack? Get a grip! ...Google is not a friend, and should not be trusted. This is not the time or place for a discussion about that, but there's nothing personal about not trusting Google.